# Google App Script: Fetch all URLs from column A, and individually openByURL,getSheetByName, getRange, getValues, then setValues in master sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am quite new to Google App Scripts, but have had some success with retrieving values from a single Google Sheet, but have no idea how to modify the code to be dynamic and fetch the URLs from a column instead.

**How would I loop this function to go through a list of Google Sheet URLS in the destination sheet, so I don't have to manually add each URL?**

Here is my current code that works great for a single sheet.

```
function copypaste(sourcelink,sourcesheet,sourcerange,destilink,destisheet,destirange) {
  
  //Source Link
  var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourcelink);
  var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName(sourcesheet);
  var range = sheetraw.getRange(sourcerange);
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  //Destination
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destilink);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destisheet);
  
  //Transfer to destination range
  sheet.getRange(destirange).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(destirange).setValues(data);

}

// This function will add rows to destination sheet to ensure they match the source, to avoid any errors.
function startImport() {

  //Calculate number of rows in source
  var object = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/#1/edit").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A2:B").getValues()
  var rownumber = object.length

  //Calculate number of rows in destination
  var object2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/#2/edit").getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A1:B").getValues()
  var rownumber2 = object2.length

  //Add rows based on differences
  var addrows = rownumber - rownumber2
  if(addrows>0){ 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("[DATA PULL] Roster Offshore").insertRowsAfter(rownumber2,addrows)
  }
  
  //Refreshes sheet, so the next lines of code do not give an error that the rows are still not the same.
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  
  //Imports the data into destination.
    copypaste("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/#1/edit",
            "Sheet1",
            "A2:B",
            "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/#2/edit",
            "Sheet2",
            "A1:B")
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you want to copy these same values to multuiple google sheets, rather than just the one you are copying them over to now in the `startImport` function?

Comment: I have a master file Google Sheet, and I have around 100 other Google Sheets. I am looking to import all the other Google Sheets, into the Master Google Sheet. You will notice in the code, I have to manually specify the URL. Instead I would like the script to retrieve the URL from the master sheet containing a column of URL's

Comment: Ah, got it. So you essentially have a spreadsheet where column, say, A, has 100 rows, each containing a URL. You want a script to grab all of those URLs and plop them into an array to be looped through?

Comment: Exactly! :D

I just found a video on YouTube that demonstrates exactly what I am trying to achieve. The only difference, is in this video, he is using a Google Drive directory to create the array. In my situation, I am looking to use a column of URLs to create the array.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-X5CxT2fPbM

Comment: Perfect. In an answer to the question, let me leave you the code to grab those URLs from a sheet and you can let me know if that gives you what you need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grab the list of spreadsheet URLs from a spreadsheet, you can use the following code snippet:

```
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
const sheetName = "xxxx"; // Please enter the sheet name you are grabbing data from
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
const rangeA1 = "A7:B11"; // Please modify this range accordingly to where the values are stored
const range = sheet.getRange(rangeA1);
const vals = range.getValues();
const finalListOfURLs = vals.flat(); // In case your URLs span multiple columns, this will flatten it into a 1D array.
console.log(finalListOfURLs);
```

Please let me know if that does what you need! (This would specifically give you the list of URLs as an array, nothing else.)

Comment: Looks great. Getting an error though `TypeError: range.getValues is not a function (line 7, file "Code")`

Comment: Whoops, you're totally right, sorry. Just made needed changes!

Comment: So glad, sure thing!